# angular translate save translations to database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I want to use Angular-translate in my project. I have a basic example working with some basic hard coded translation strings.
Users are able to change the language 'on the fly', so the strings change directly after a new choice.

I want to get my translations from a MongoDB collection. I have found a example for that (https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/blob/920a9febc22f61368153d844f7cbefcfebb6ecec/src/service/loader-url.js) using a custom loader service.

But, I want to get my translation keys automatically in that collection when there is no translation available. Is there a way to do that? 
The keyword must be saved, so a translator can add the missing strings via a web panel.

Answer (score -1):

This is not implementation, this is just an idea. You can make following structure of the MongoDB table. 
Table Name: languageTable

columns

```
id, key,  en, el, sp, hi,

1. KEY1, Hello, $tUpp4, dd4$53, ff553,
```

(the language translations for the different langugaes)
Now in the queryparam, send the key and langkey. and use following query,

```
Select `LangKey` from languageTable where key = 'KEY1;'
```

if it returns the text then show that otherwise show null. And in the admin panel you can display the complete table and perform the crud operation on the language table.

Thanks Good Luck

Comment: That's what I have working now, but I want to save key's in my database where no database record is found for.